# Line spacing in title with titling

Tags: spacing, titles

I would like to reduce the line spacing in the title. How could I do so?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\scshape\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\large\scshape\lineskip 0.5em\begin{tabular}[t]{l r}}
\postauthor{&}
\predate{\large\scshape}
\postdate{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat {name=\section,numberless}{\large\scshape\filcenter}{}{0pt}{}

\title{Some very long title which has more than one row.}
\author{The author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `\linespread` just before  entering the `center` environment in `\pretitle`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\linespread{0.6}\begin{center}\LARGE\scshape\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\large\scshape\lineskip 0.5em\begin{tabular}[t]{l r}}
\postauthor{&}
\predate{\large\scshape}
\postdate{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat {name=\section,numberless}{\large\scshape\filcenter}{}{0pt}{}

\title{Some very long title which has more than one row.}
\author{The author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]